# nginx not run php by location

Tags: nginx, phppgadmin

I should get `phppgadmin` by `example.com/phppgadmin`, but something is going wrong. I could get it by `example.com/` (see the comments in conf below). But if I'm trying to get `phppgadmin` by creating `location`in nginx config I'm getting `404 not found`. What am I doing wrong? `Error.log` is fine.

Here is the `nginx` conf:

```
server {

        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name example.com;

        #This path works. We are getting phppgadmin by example.com/ , 
        #but I need to get it by location (example.com/phppgadmin):
        #root /usr/share/phppgadmin;

        #This should work but it doesn't:
        location /phppgadmin/ {  

        root /usr/share;

        }

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you place `root /usr/share;` in the `server` block (where the original `root` statement was), the URI `example.com/phppgadmin/` would work as expected.

But, it would also expose the entire contents of the `/usr/share` directory, which you may not want.

You can place the `root` statement inside a `location` but you need to include all of the directives necessary to process the request.

For example:

```
location ^~ /phppgadmin/ {  
    root /usr/share;
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

The `^~` modifier avoids any ambiguity with URIs ending with `.php`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.